# Crtmpserver convert rtmp stream to rtsp stream

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ffmpeg, rtsp, rtmp

i was installed crtmpserver in my AWS EC2 and i was created RTMP live Stream url ,it's working fine now. After this i am try to stream to my live video to RTSP url ,i was insert the
 `inboundRtsp` in application .

```
{
        ip="0.0.0.0",
        port=5544,
        protocol="inboudRtsp"
},
```

but it' does not working. Now how can i stream
the `Crtmp RTMP url` to `Crtmp Rtsp url`. please help any one. i know the wowza did this and also ffmpeg can re-stream it. But i need only in crtmpserver. please guide me any one

Answer (score 0):

The default transport layer port number for RTSP is 554 for both TCP and UDP, the latter being rarely used for the control requests.

You, however, are using 5544 here, just because you want to run crtmpserver as a regular user only. Hence you will also need to specify this (5544) port number while accessing this service.

OTOH, if you run crtmpserver as either as super-user (root) or by specifying --uid and, or -gid you must/can edit your configuration file and change that 5544 to default port 554 as well.

Answer (score 0):

=========>             protocol="inboudRtsp"

you forget a "n", like protocol="inboundRtsp"

and yes, the default port for rtsp is 554